# system cannot found the file

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am getting this error when I'm using  `.jrxml`  file in *NetBeans* applications

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \schoolmngt\FirstReport.jrxml (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Compi   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:174)

The code id

```
    try{
    System.out.println("Compiling report...");
        JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile("/schoolmngt/FirstReport.jrxml");
                System.out.println("Filling report...");
      JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile("/schoolmngt/FirstReport.jasper",new HashMap(), new JREmptyDataSource());
   //JasperRunManager.runReportToHtmlFile("FirstReport.jasper",new HashMap(),new JREmptyDataSource());
      JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfFile("/schoolmngt/FirstReport.jasper",new HashMap(),new JREmptyDataSource());
    }
    catch(Exception ee){ee.printStackTrace();}
```

My file path is:

```
D:\Schoolmngt\src\schoolmngt\FirstReport.jrxml
```

When I run the project this error is coming regularly please tell me the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Relative paths do not start with `/`. `/schoolmngt/FirstReport.jrxml` is an absolute path.

If the current drive is `D:` it will look for `D:/schoolmngt/FirstReport.jrxml`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I didn't have time to resolve it so I just provided the full path (starting with drive letter) and it worked. I know it doesn't really fix the problem properly, but if want to just make it working for now try it.

Answer (score 0):

The path in your code should be **src/schoolmngt/FirstReport.jrxml**.